# Get the type of AnyObject in Swift

Tags: swift, skspritenode

I have custom `SkSpriteNode` subclass. The name of this class is `Unit1`.

In `GameScene`:

```
var allUnit1:[Unit1]?
var enemy1 = Unit1(imageNamed: "1")
enemy1.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(StartPointX), CGFloat(self.frame.height))

// I add this custom node to array. Its not relative with my 
// question but I want to describe all of them.

if(allUnit1 == nil) {
    allUnit1 = [enemy1]
}
else {
    allUnit1?.append(enemy1)
}

self.addChild(enemy1)
self.getDamage2Unit(self.allUnit1!.first!) 

// My function in gamescene. The problem starts with here. the parameter is AnyObject 
// as you see in below
```

and `getDamage2Unit` function is (its in `GameScene` too);

```
func getDamage2Unit(val:AnyObject){
     if(val.type == "Unit1")
        println("this AnyObject is Unit1 objects")
    }
}
```

This `if` condition doesn't work. I am looking for something like that. I need to know this anyObject's real type. How do I know that?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using `AnyObject` as the argument type in `getDamage2Unit`? Do you need to be able to pass many different types of units to it? Because, a better way could be to use protocols or a common superclass or function overloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
func getDamage2Unit(val:AnyObject){
     if let myType = val as? Unit1 {
        println("this AnyObject is Unit1 objects")
    }
}
```

Now if you know that val will be always of type `Unit1`, then change `AnyObject` to `Unit1`

or

```
func getDamage2Unit(val:AnyObject) {
let myType = val as Unit1?
         if myType != nil {
            println("this AnyObject is Unit1 objects")
        }
    }
```